# Errors in Python daemon process aren't propagated to Terminal?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a daemon process in Python that I create using the following code:

```
process = mp.Process(name="test", target=run, args=(chunk_queue, res_queues))
process.daemon = True
process.start()
```

I can confirm that this daemon can print to Terminal. However, it seems like unless I explicitly code something like a ValueError, errors that occur in the daemon process (TypeErrors, out of range errors, etc.) don't seem to be propagated to Terminal; rather, the process seems to silently stop.

Is there a way I can propagate these errors to the Terminal?

Comment: For a true daemon (vs the Python definition) this is obligatory. A daemon has to survive the terminal it was started from getting closed, so it can't have any file handles open to that terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When a error occurs, you can add the error to a list, if it is not empty, print it.

````
import multiprocessing as mp

def run(chunk_queue, res_queues, error_queue):
    try:
        () # daemon code...
    except Exception as e:
        error_queue.put(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    chunk_queue, res_queues, error_queue = mp.Queue(), mp.Queue(), mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(name="test", target=run, args=(chunk_queue, res_queues, error_queue))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join()
    if not error_queue.empty():
        print(f"Error: {error_queue.get()}")```
````